# I must teach someone how a dSLR works at work. Where can I find an animation for this?

Tags: exposure, aperture, shutter-speed

I must teach someone how a dSLR works at work. So YouTube, Vimeo and, generally, videos are banned.

My 'apprentice' is smart, however I feel that he needs an animation with a 'transparent' (CGI) dSLR showing how the aperture's blades are closing, the mirror is lifted, (optionally) the curtains are open, and the sensor is exposed for a certain amount of time. I need to show him what means 'aperture' and 'shutter speed' in a visual way. I searched for exposure basics on internet and found different diagrams and articles but I'm looking now for something visual.

Where can I find an animation for this?

Comment: Why on Earth are videos not allowed? They seem an ideal way to teach this.

Comment: Something 'visual' but no video... Does your apprentice has a serious photosensitivity problem or a maybe a form of epilepsy ? What kind of animation are you looking for ? Limitation on frame rate ?

Comment: I expect that videos per se are not banned, but that these popular video sharing sites are blocked as a matter of policy at John's workpace.

Comment: @mattdm is correct. We have a firewall which blocks these sites and file extensions like .mp4 .avi etc. The reason is obvious: To spend the entire working time watching videos.

Comment: To teach him outside of work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something which shows quite clearly whats happening at:

http://camerasim.com/apps/dslr-explained/

It is good because it has a step by step mode, different lighting conditions and, also, it shows the resulting photo.

Answer (score 2):

This webpage:

http://digital-photography-school.com/photography-1016-shutter/

Has some animations on how the shutter curtains in a dSLR work to control the shutter speed, but nothing on the mirror.

Comment: should have started with DPS, I use that site all the time.